# How do I filter a dataframe to return a specific type of record, after I have used group by on the dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

came here last night with a question regarding group by, and found a pretty quick solution! I'm trying to solve a problem now though where I can return a data frame with just one of the multiple 'complaint_type' I have in my df, however, my df is grouped by 'complaint_type'

I've tried just using a normal filter statement however, it says that I have a key error. Below shows my df, along with the statement I used.

```py
# Original Data Frame

NY311_df

# Creating a new df from the original based on group by

b_ct_df = NY311_df.groupby(['borough','complaint_type']).count()

#Trying to return the same df, but only where the complaint type is 
#'HEAT/HOT WATER'

b_ct_df[b_ct_df['complaint_type']=='HEAT/HOT WATER']

#The line above returns the error 'complaint_type' KeyError
```

I want to return the complaint_type of 'Heat/Hot Water' for each borough. I expect it to look something like this Bronx:Heat/Hot Water: 456, Brooklyn:Heat/Hot Water: 543, etc...

Just at a lost for what is causing the error here. Cheers.

Comment: `complaint_type` is not a column of `b_ct_df`, it is level 1 index. So you want to do `b_ct_df[b_ct_df.index.get_level_values(1)=='HEAT/HOT WATER']`.

Comment: Thank you! This solves my probem, I was unaware of the index transform when doing groupby, (new to DS), appreciate the help for a newbie.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternativ to to comment solution you can do:

```
b_ct_df = NY311_df.groupby(['borough','complaint_type']).count().reset_index()
b_ct_df[b_ct_df['complaint_type']=='HEAT/HOT WATER']
```

or you could do:

```
b_ct_df = NY311_df[NY311_df['complaint_type']=='HEAT/HOT WATER'].groupby(['borough','complaint_type']).count()
```

Comment: thanks man, i like the options here. it looks like to me, that you're essentially making python understand that even though 'complaint_type is an index, to ignore it and treat it as a column?

Comment: yes, but there are always several other options to perform this kind of calculations